# Sort list of tuples in ascending order based on value at index 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
```

Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below.
**Expected output:**

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

**Code:**

```
fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')


fhand = open(fname)

c = dict()

for line in fhand:

  if not line.startswith('From ') : continue

  pieces = line.split()

  time = pieces[5]

  parts = time.split(':')

  hour = parts[0]
  c[hour] = c.get(hour,0) + 1

lst = list()
for key in c:
  value = c[key]
  lst.append( (value, key) )

lst.sort()

for value, key in lst:
  print key, value
```

**Output I got**

```
06 1 ← Mismatch
07 1
14 1
18 1
19 1
09 2
15 2
17 2
04 3
10 3
16 4
11 6
```

Comment: Your question title could be hugely improved. From the title alone, it's clear that this question won't benefit anybody else in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lst` is a *list of tuple* with each tuple holding the value in the format *(value, key)* . And you want to sort it based on the *key* which is at index `1` of the tuple. In that case you should be calling the `.sort()` with key as:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
```

OR, you may also use *lambda expression* as key:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

---

Also, you do not have to create a separate list in order to print the sorted content. You may iterate on the sorted `dict` object using `sorted(c.items())`. Hence, you may do:

```
for key, value in sorted(c.items()):
    print key, value
```

instead of:

```
lst = list()
for key in c:
  value = c[key]
  lst.append( (value, key) )

lst.sort()

for value, key in lst:
  print key, value
```

Comment: Tuples are first sorted by their first element by default, so this would be the same behavior as sorting without a key (except that items with the same first element would keep their original order with this). Did you mean element `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks for pointing it out. I missed that OP tuple is having reverse pair as `(value, key)` pair